# When should I use enum instead of domain and vice versa?

Tags: java, grails

My context: User will add one of numerous type of company into himself in the form. For that form, I created `enum` to fill the listbox instead of pulling the database.

I will try my best to explain what my question is: In my context, whats the difference between using `enum` and `domain` for showing and save into database? Performance, logic, bestpractice?

Because when user saves a `companyType`, it will save an `int` into database, but I can see what `description` it is. using a method `@Overide toString()`.

Instead of using `enum` as code below, I could have created a domain with `id` and `description` moreover adding two registers into my db pulling into to form.

```
class Company{
    CompanyType companyType
}
```

Use this as enum

```
enum CompanyType {
    MARKET('Market', 1),
    SHOP('Shop', 2)
// ... etc of code
}
```

or use this as domain

```
class CompanyType {
    Long id
    String description
}
```

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I have never heard of `domain` in [java]? Is that tag really the one you wanted to use?

Comment: Unclear what your real question is here; do you want to map some Java type to a given column in the database?

Comment: No, I want to know what's the difference using the domain or enum for show and save into database.

Comment: If I did understand your question, in brief, you want to know if it's better to have a CompanyType table and a corresponding CompanyType POJO class, which you are relating to as domain, or just a CompanyType enum, is that so ?

Comment: Just the table. Or just the enum companyType

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main factor you should consider is how much the Company type data may change, if you are able to list all the possible company types you will be using and are sure that no frequent update are expected, then the enum is the reasonable choice, no table or POJO needed, in the other hand, if it's meant to change, adding, updating and removing company type, then the table and the POJO class are the right choice.

Answer (score 3):

two points:

- performance: enum values are saved as a String (usually as `enum.toString()`) in a db, and don't require any FK-relations and have less overhead during ORM transformations
- flexibility: enum values can be updated only with new deployment. If you need to change the value of the existing enum constant, you would have to migrate your data

I would use enums instead of a domain class, as the performance is usually more important